# How to find the second string between two strings

Tags: php

I have been working on a script that pulls information from a certain website. The said website pulls the information from a database and displays it in a way the user can easily read it (like always).

Imagine it looks like this:

**Var1**: result1
**Var2:** result2
**Var3:** result3

What my script does is that it reads the page's source code and retrieves "result1", "result2" and "result3" by obtaining the text between two strings.

Sample code:

```
<?php

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {

        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);

    }

    function check($url) {

        // usually, $fullstring = file_get_contents($url);
        $fullstring = "<string1>result1</string1><string1>result2</string1><string1>result3</string1>";

        $result = get_string_between($fullstring, "<string1>", "</string1>");

        echo "<b>Result: </b>".$result;

    }

    check("random");    // just to execute the function

?>
```

In case you wonder why I have the check() function there it is because this code is part of something bigger and I need a solution that works in this case scenario, so I tried to keep it immaculate.

Now, I can easily get "result1" because it's the first occurrence, but how can I get "result2" and "result3"?

Thank you :)

Comment: [Does this article help](http://frankkoehl.com/2009/03/second-third-fourth-occurence-string/)?

Comment: I had to re-read the code a few times, but I understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Matt I found the sample very helpful, it represents another way to do this and it is definitely a relevant example for this situation. The problem is that I don't know exactly how many occurrences of the string I will be dealing with and what the strings will look like(I should have stated this in the original question). In case I am misunderstanding the code, doesn't it retrieve the position of a certain string(that you define)?

Comment: Check out @nickb's answer. That will get you what you need.  If you return the entire array of matches that his code gives you, you can then iterate through it using a `foreach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex to extract all of the matches, then pick the ones you want:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) 
{
    preg_match_all( '/' . preg_quote( $start, '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote( $end, '/') . '/', $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

The regex will capture anything between the `$start` and `$end` variables.

Now the function returns an array of all of the result values, which you can pick which one you want:

```
list( $first, $second, $third) = get_string_between( $string,  "<string1>", "</string1>");
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/MBiV8k).

Comment: Take it a step further and you can add `$matches` as a reference parameter `function get_string_between($string, $start, $end, &$matches) {...}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have two questions. 1) What can I do if I don't know the number of occurrences (i can have 1,2,3,4,5..200 times <string1>text</string1>) and 2) How can I retrieve ONLY "result1" instead of "string 'result1' (length=7)"? Thanks again

Comment: Or you can return $matches and the programmer can then process it as an `array` instead of just a string.

Comment: This returns an array - It'll work with any number of occurrences. Your second question is trivial and shows a lack of understanding of the language - The output you're seeing is from `var_dump()` to show you the type of the variable. If you just did `echo $first;` on my demo, you wouldn't get `var_dump()`'s output.

Comment: @nickb Yes, I do lack knowledge when it comes to php and I realise it shows, that is probably the reason why I will be asking the following question, one that looks basic to you: How can I make it work with a random number of occurrences? In your example you set $list( $first, $second, $third), implying we only have three occurrences.

Comment: You would replace `list( ...) = ` with `$array = `. Now, you have an array of all the matches. If you want the first match, do `echo $array[0];`, or you can use a `foreach` loop to iterate over all of the matches.